# Using Gradle and the gradle-gae-plugin debug parameters are not passed

Tags: gradle

I'm using gradle to build, run, deploy my Google App Engine project.  The [gradle-gae-plugin](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-gae-plugin) (version 0.4) seems to work perfect with one caveat.  The debug parameters are never passed to the local running engine during gaeRun.

I've changed the http port, so I see at least one parameter taking effect.  However, my IDE is rejected on the default 8000 debug port, and netstat shows nothing listening on 8000.

Here is the gae closure from my build.gradle:

```
gae {
    httpPort = 8888
    debug = true
    debugPort = 8000
}
```

And the informational log statement coming out of GaeRunTask.groovy of the gradle-gae-plugin

```
[INFO] [org.gradle.api.plugins.gae.task.GaeRunTask] Using params = [com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain, --port=8888, /[project-dir]/war/build/exploded-war]
```

gradle version

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 1.0-milestone-3
------------------------------------------------------------

Gradle build time: Monday, 25 April 2011 5:40:11 PM EST
Groovy: 1.7.10
Ant: Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 20 2010
Ivy: 2.2.0
JVM: 1.6.0_23 (Sun Microsystems Inc. 19.0-b09)
OS: Linux 2.6.38-8-generic amd64
```

Comment: Can you run your script with the '-d' flag and see what other output you get from the plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because version 0.4 does not support the debug flag yet. I am currently working on version 0.5 and had already checked in the changes for the README.md file on master. Please refer to tag [v0.4](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-gae-plugin/tree/v0.4) for available convention properties in version 0.4. I will probably push the next version within the upcoming week. As soon as I do I will let you know.

Comment: I just released version 0.5 which includes the JVM remote debug convention properties.